# CSS Responsive Design Break Points

Tags: html, css

I'm using Break points at 768 480 & 225. Is this sufficient for my responsive design or is more recommended.

768 + | Computer

480 - 768 | Tablet

225 - 480 | Smart Phone

225 < | Phone / Min Browser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't even worry about trying to design for types of displays, there are too many resolutions to possibly make decisions based on that.

Instead, just start with your maximum resolution on your display, and slowly shrink the browser window until you find the natural breakpoints for your content, and fix them as they come up.  If you do this, then it won't matter what resolutions are out there, and it will be future-proof for new displays.

You definitely don't have to throw away your current break points, just check them to see if there's any more you need to add or a way to make your current ones more efficient.

[Here's a Smashing Mag article that goes further into the topic.](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/24/beyond-common-media-query-breakpoints/)