# @media queries to exclude iOS device in SASS

Tags: ios, css, ipad, sass

I'm currently try to create proper @media queries to target 3 different device groups: phones, tablets and desktops

I use the following mixin in SASS to get it done:

```
@mixin respond-to($media) {
  @if $media == phones {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $media == tablets {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 979px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $media == desktops {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 980px) { @content; }
  }
}
```

This actually works pretty well for most devices i have around.
BUT i have an iPad 2 here and tried the site with Safari and the following happens:

in portrait mode everything is fine. it will be handled by the "tablet" group as it should be.
in landscape mode (when it has 1024px width to work with) it will still fall into the tablet group. But it shouldnt as my layout works perfectly on screens wider than 980px.

As i found out the iOS devices always report their screen size as they were in portrait mode (actually a stupid idea) which in my case is 768x1024. With the media queries above it will never end up in the non-tablet section when its in landscape.

is there a way to exclude the ipad 2 in landscape mode from the tablet query WITHOUT disturbing other devices (like androids which behave correctly)?

Otherwise i have to target every device seperatly with their own strict media query which i want to avoid.

Comment: You're really going to be fighting an uphill battle with specific breakpoints like this. Have you thought about just letting your content determine the breakpoints instead? I answered an SO question about this recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352108/css-responsive-design-break-points/14352206#14352206 , also check out this new post by Brad Frost, specifically the first section http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/

Comment: The breakpoints are from the content. i have to apply my mid size screen rules below 980 and even different ones below 320. As i wrote: works fine on most devices. only the ipad drives me mad by not react when its actual can display >980 but still uses the <980 section.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the problem is due to your viewport meta tag. The following is what I use on all responsive sites:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```